# How to access session token with next-auth in order to attach it to a API request header?

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth, js-cookie

Hello I'm new to **NextJS** and **React**, but my project currently has a 3rd party api that I'm working with that requires a session token input in the header for all requests.

So I picked `next-Auth` for authentication but I have problem accessing that chunk of raw jwt.

> I tried `useSession` but it only gives me info within **JWT** (users, expiration, etc). I found a server side function in documentation called `getToken()` but the sample requires a line like this:

```
const secret = process.env.SECRET
```

Does that mean i need the secret key to the jwt signature in order to retrieve the raw jwt?

I can see that session token in my cookie under my localhost file and I tried to use **js-cookie** to `get()` that cookie, but I still can't get deeper to get the inner `cookies`. I wonder how I should approach this problem and what's the proper way to attach session token in API requests for next-auth setup.

Thanks!